# Amazon Lex - Lambda function doesn't return voice when the "content" has HTML tags

Tags: aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have built my chat-bot with `AWS Lex`. The Chat bot returns **text** as well as **voice** when there is no HTML tags in the message, from Lambda function. However, when I add HTML tags to style the text output, Lambda doesn't return the voice.

```
     var message = {
        'contentType': 'PlainText', 
        'content': 'We offer x,y,z. For more information, visit our <a href="www.xyz.com">website</a>'
    }
```

The Text output of the above is "*We offer x,y,z. For more information, visit out website" (Where website is a hyperlink)*" but voice returns an error message.

However if I removed anchor tags from the string both text and voice return the correct output. I need to style my output therefore I need HTML tags to the string. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of my question. Anyone who might be struggling to do this, please look at the below code:

```
 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var outputmode =  event.outputDialogMode);
 }
```

You can find out which mode user wants to converse with and alter your response accordingly.